# Use a loop, perform regression, predict new values for each person

Tags: r

I have a data set with 20 variables. 10 of them are variables of great interest but these variables need to be adjusted for group differences in terms of age and sex. I do this by using regression, to predict values depending on age and sex.

There are many variables, and many persons, so I want a loop or similar.

Here is an example of what I'm attempting

```
# Load example data
library(survival)
library(dplyr)
data(lung) # example data

# I want to obtain adjusted values for the following two variables, called "dependents"
dependents <- names(select(lung, 7:8))

new_data <- lung # copies data set
for (i in seq_along(dependents)) {
     eq <- paste(dependents[i],"~ age + sex")
     fit <- lm(as.formula(eq), data= new_data)
     new_data$predicted_value <- predict(fit, newdata=new_data, type='response')
     new_data <- rename(new_data, paste(dependents[i], "_predicted", sep="") = predicted_value)
}
View(new_data)
```

This failed to provide me with the "dependents" in adjusted (i.e predicted) form.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach, using the tidyr package and the `augment` function from my broom package:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

new_data <- lung %>%
  gather(dependent, value, ph.karno:pat.karno) %>%
  group_by(dependent) %>%
  do(augment(lm(value ~ age + sex, data = .)))
```

This reorganizes the data so that each dependent (`ph.karno` and `pat.karno`) is stacked on top of each other, distinguished by a `dependent` column. The `augment` function turns each model into a data frame with columns for fitted values, residuals, and other values you care about (see `?lm_tidiers` for more). The `.fitted` column then gives the fitted values:

```
new_data
#> Source: local data frame [452 x 12]
#> Groups: dependent
#> 
#>    dependent .rownames value age sex  .fitted  .se.fit     .resid
#> 1   ph.karno         1    90  74   1 78.86709 1.406553  11.132915
#> 2   ph.karno         2    90  68   1 80.53347 1.115994   9.466530
#> 3   ph.karno         3    90  56   1 83.86624 1.226463   6.133759
#> 4   ph.karno         4    90  57   1 83.58851 1.181024   6.411490
#> 5   ph.karno         5   100  60   1 82.75532 1.078170  17.244683
#> 6   ph.karno         6    50  74   1 78.86709 1.406553 -28.867085
#> 7   ph.karno         7    70  68   2 80.18860 1.419744 -10.188596
#> 8   ph.karno         8    60  71   2 79.35540 1.555365 -19.355404
#> 9   ph.karno         9    70  53   1 84.69943 1.388600 -14.699433
#> 10  ph.karno        10    70  61   1 82.47759 1.056850 -12.477586
#> ..       ...       ...   ... ... ...      ...      ...        ...
#> Variables not shown: .hat (dbl), .sigma (dbl), .cooksd (dbl), .std.resid
#>   (dbl)
```

As one way you could use this data, you could graph how the predictions for the dependent variables differ:

```
ggplot(new_data, aes(age, .fitted, color = dependent, lty = factor(sex))) +
     geom_line()
```

If you're looking to *control* for the age and sex, however, you probably want to work with the `.resid` column.

Comment: I love the broom package by the way! And your answer worked out well; only drawback is the final data set being in long format but one can live with that i guess =)

Comment: @AdamRobinsson I actually think long format is usually much easier to work with ([see here for more on that](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper)). But you can get it into a wide format with `spread` if you wanted, for example with `resids <- new_data %>% select(dependent, .resid) %>% spread(dependent, .resid)`

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just do this?

```
dependents <- names(lung)[7:8]
fit <- lm(as.formula(sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ age + sex", 
                      paste(dependents, collapse = ", "))), 
          data = lung)
predict(fit)
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion; it did not exactly fit my purpose, which is presumably because I could not explain my question better, but I have saved the code since It will definitely come in handy in the future! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

And a third approach.

```
new_data <- na.omit(lung[,c("sex","age",dependents)])
result <- lapply(new_data[,dependents],
                 function(y)predict(lm(y~age+sex,data.frame(y=y,new_data[,c("age","sex")]))))
names(result) <- paste(names(result),"predicted",sep="_")
result <- cbind(new_data,as.data.frame(result))
head(result)
#   sex age ph.karno pat.karno ph.karno_predicted pat.karno_predicted
# 1   1  74       90       100           78.83030            77.34670
# 2   1  68       90        90           80.59974            78.53841
# 3   1  56       90        90           84.13862            80.92183
# 4   1  57       90        60           83.84371            80.72321
# 5   1  60      100        90           82.95899            80.12736
# 6   1  74       50        80           78.83030            77.34670
```

Your original code has a couple of subtle problems (other than the fact that it doesn't run). The response variables have a few `NA`s, which are removed automatically by `lm(...)`, so the prediction has fewer rows that the original data set, and when you try to add the new column with, e.g.

```
 new_data$predicted_value <- predict(fit, newdata=new_data, type='response')
```

you get an error. You have to remove the `NA`s from new_data first, as shown in the code above.

I'm also wondering, since your data seems to be counts of something, if you should be using a poisson glm instead of lm?

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, which did work out!
Considering the count data and glam; the lung data set was only used to provide a reproducible example. My data set differs and I did not specifically lookup these variables in the lung data set =)